# Why is object_a != object_b, if they have the exact same id, type, and attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, equals, comparison-operators

I have two User objects that should be the same, but ruby is saying they are not. Can anyone please explain to me what is going on here?

```
a = current_user  
b = votable.user

a == b  
false   
a.id == b.id  
true  
a.name == b.name  
true  
a.attributes == b.attributes  
true
```

### Updates / additional information since the original posting:

- Turns out the problem I'm having is intermittent. It occurs about 30% of the time I refresh the page in question. 70% of the time, A == B and everything works as expected. But 30% of the time, A does not equal B.
- When the problem occurs, Ruby is actually telling me that the class (type) of my objects is not the same, even though they look identical (User and User). Here's the output for that 30% of the time when the problem is happening:

.

```
a.class == b.class AKA a.type == b.type
false (note: this is a correction to the original post which said true)
a.class.to_s
"User"
b.class.to_s
"User"
a.class.name == b.class.name
true
a.class.methods == b.class.methods
true
a.class.object_id == b.class.object_id
false
```

So the class (type) of the objects *looks* exactly the same. It is said to be User. But when you evaluate a.class == b.class, the answer is false the 30% of the time when I render the page, causing the problem.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Many thanks.

➜  ~  ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
➜  ~  rails --version
Rails 3.0.10

Comment: Without knowing ruby on rails I guess they don't share the same location in memory. You should overload the == operator to check for equality by means of id, type, name and attributes.

Comment: @Matten, Ruby on Rails overrides ==.  It checks record.id and record.class.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If `a == b` is false then I'm guessing it's doing something like `a.object_id == b.object_id` which would only be true if the references are pointing to the same object.

`a.id == b.id` is probably just checking the `User.id` and it makes sense that it would be true.

Easiest thing to do is keep checking on `User.id`. If you really want to use `==` you'll need to override it in the User class with something like:

```
class User
  def ==(other)
    self.id == other.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of objects these are. Do they just decent from `Object`?

`Object#==` really just does `Object#===` unless you override `#==` and define a more appropriate behavior. For `Object#==`= to be true they have to actually be references to the SAME OBJECT, not equivalent objects.

Just define a `#==` method and use some sane logic to determine if two objects are the same... then you can use `a == b` and get `true`.

If these are `ActiveRecord::Base` descendants then something else is going on, as `ActiveRecord::Base` objects do have a sane `#==` method (though you can overwrite that behavior too).

Answer (score 0):

The two objets are not the same object. They are, however, referencing the same user in the database.

I suggest that you compare them on the `id` as you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3 and assuming each of your methods above returns an ActiveRelation (or at a minimum, one of them does). Then it would be safe to say that the first comparison is right, as each ActiveRelation probably is a different object.

My answer makes a few assumptions about your code, but might help offer some insight.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-3D-3D , the equality operator should be checking type and id.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 1811
def ==(comparison_object)
  super ||
    comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) &&
    id.present? &&
    comparison_object.id == id
end
```

What must be happening is that they are not the same class.  Could you please check and output the results?

```
votable.user.class
current_user.class
```

Comment: You are correct to say that what may be happening is that they are not the same class. See my updates to the question above. votable.user.class => "User". current_user.class => "User". But about 30% of the time Ruby still says they are different classes, even though they are both "User".

Answer (score -2):

Logicl explanation:

They have simmilar attributes, but they are different essentially. Note that the Earth and the Marth are different planets, even if we only look at the facts that both of them are in the Milky Way galaxy and both of them are planets.

If an object is like another object it is not necessarily the same.

Technical explanation:

When you create an object a reference to the object will be created. If you create another object another reference will be created.

If you have object A and object.

```
a = current_user  
b = votable.user
a == b
false

a = current_user  
b = a
a== b
true
```

Two objects are equal if their reference is the same (and their attributes are the same too, of course). You can always write methods to define new equivalence relations if the standard relations are not enough ;)

Comment: Well, thank you for the downvotes, if you are right, I will have the oportunity, to learn something. However, I would need some comments about the downvote, to understand where/if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: sorry. My downvote was essentially directed against the way you explain it. Why this obscure and confusing reference about the planets ? and what planet is "Marth" ? You should stick to the "technical" explanation, and the one you give is not even crystal-clear itself (why not use the concept of "object id" instead of this blurry concept of "reference" ?).